# can not parse JsonArray by gson

Tags: android, json, gson

This is my `json`:

```
{
    "message":"Success",
    "method":"getList",
    "values": [
        {
            "_id":"2"
        }
    ]
}
```

There are two model classes:

```
public class ModelList {
    @SerializedName("message")
    public String MESSAGE;

    @SerializedName("method")
    public String METHOD;

    public List<ModelValue> modelValues;
}
```

and:

```
public class ModelValue {

    @SerializedName("_id")
    public String ARTIST_ID;
}
```

This is the code that I have in Activity.

```
ModelList response;

response = gson.fromJson(jsonToStringFromAssetFolder("twitter_search.json", JsonParsingActivity.this),
    ModelArtistList.class);
Toast.makeText(this, response.MESSAGE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

List<ModelValue> results = response.modelValues;

for (ModelValue result : results) {
    Toast.makeText(this, result._ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("log_tag","result.fromUser"+result._ID);
}
```

I got `NullPointerException` at: `List<ModelValue> results = response.modelValues;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this in `ModelList` class: add `@SerializedName("values")` for `modelValues`

```
public class ModelList {

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String MESSAGE;
    @SerializedName("method")
    public String METHOD;
    @SerializedName("values")
    public List<ModelValue> modelValues;
}
```

Comment: this is the only error message that you get? It should provide more details on the reason